# Where is the Agenda view for Calendar in iOS 7?

Tags: calendar, ios

I can't find the agenda for the new iOS 7 calendar.  Has it been removed?  If not, how can I view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS 7 agenda hasn't been removed, but it's not as intuitively easy to find.

To see your agenda:

In the month view, tap on any date to bring it to hourly view, then tap the icon (bullets with lines next to the search icon) this will allow you to toggle back and forth between hourly and agenda list view.

Comment: This was really annoying my wife since she upgraded to iOS 7.  After a bit of research, I found this discrete solution.  Apparently others have been bothered by this as well.